# Site not loading using curl

Tags: php, curl, loading

```
<?php
$url='https://source.amazon.com/forcelogin?returnToURL=https://www.amazon.com/';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.7) Gecko/20070914 Firefox/2.0.0.7");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,'cookies.txt'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookies.txt"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookies.txt");
$data = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch); 


?>
```

I don't know why it doesn't load the website.

If I put regular sites like google.com, amazon.com or anything else is working.Anyone can help me out?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` and `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` options to access HTTPS URL.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
```

Comment: The page still not loading ,anyway I appreciate your answer.

Comment: @drew010 I saw that you have really good knowledge about this problems and how to fix them,maybe you can help me out to .